# JPQL: SIZE function causing strange exceptions on EclipseLink

Tags: java, jpa, collections, eclipselink, jpql

I'm porting from Hibernate. What's wrong with SIZE function in the JPQL statement (assuming the mappings are correct)?:

```
SELECT NEW de.poyry.pqgenerator.view.PqListItem(
 pq.id,
 pq.name,
 pq.submissionDate,
 pe.firstName,
 pe.lastName,
 SIZE(pa))
FROM Prequalification pq
 JOIN pq.user us
 JOIN us.person pe
 LEFT JOIN pq.partnerships pa
 LEFT JOIN pa.company co
GROUP BY pq.id
```

Here's the constructor signature (the only constructor):

```
public PqListItem(Integer id, String name, Date submissionDate,
                  String ownerFirstName, String ownerLastName,
                  Integer numPartnerships)
```

The query results in:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-8023] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [^^...].
Internal Exception: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.antlr.runtime.EarlyExitException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException.syntaxError(JPQLException.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.handleRecognitionException(JPQLParser.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.addError(JPQLParser.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.reportError(JPQLParser.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.pathExpression(JPQLParser.java:2894)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.collectionValuedPathExpression(JPQLParser.java:2624)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.size(JPQLParser.java:7660)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.functionsReturningNumerics(JPQLParser.java:6710)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.arithmeticPrimary(JPQLParser.java:4762)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.arithmeticFactor(JPQLParser.java:4660)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.arithmeticTerm(JPQLParser.java:4546)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.simpleArithmeticExpression(JPQLParser.java:4462)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.scalarExpression(JPQLParser.java:4834)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.constructorItem(JPQLParser.java:1980)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.constructorExpression(JPQLParser.java:1849)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.selectExpression(JPQLParser.java:1300)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.selectItem(JPQLParser.java:1169)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.selectClause(JPQLParser.java:1081)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.selectStatement(JPQLParser.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.document(JPQLParser.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.parse(JPQLParser.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.buildParseTree(JPQLParser.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1475)
    ... 139 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.antlr.runtime.EarlyExitException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.pathExpression(JPQLParser.java:2882)
    ... 161 more
```

The `SIZE(pa)` seems to cause problems. When changing to `SIZE(pq.partnerships)` I get:

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-6137] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: An Exception was thrown while executing a ReportQuery with a constructor expression: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: de.poyry.pqgenerator.view.PqListItem.<init>(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String, java.util.Date, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, int)
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=Prequalification jpql="SELECT NEW de.poyry.pqgenerator.view.PqListItem(pq.id, pq.name, pq.submissionDate, pe.firstName, pe.lastName, SIZE(pq.partnerships)) FROM Prequalification pq  JOIN pq.user us  JOIN us.person pe  LEFT JOIN pq.partnerships pa  LEFT JOIN pa.company co GROUP BY pq.id")
Default FetchGroup(){id, partnerships, submissionDate, nodes, designSheets, name, statuses, group, user, tendering, isLocked}
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.exceptionWhileUsingConstructorExpression(QueryException.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ConstructorReportItem.initialize(ConstructorReportItem.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReportQuery.prepare(ReportQuery.java:1044)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.checkPrepare(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:839)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.prepareCall(DatabaseQuery.java:1719)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1475)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:468)
    at de.poyry.pqgenerator.service.PqService.findAllPqs(PqService.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5366)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5338)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5326)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
    ... 106 more
```

Looks like not autoboxing is occurring? The type of the last constructor param is Integer. Strange, it should work IMO.

Can anyone help please? I'm using EclipseLink 2.3.2 on GlassFish 3.1.1.

How do you correctly determine the number of partnerships from within the query? What does the JPA define here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SIZE` function is defined in the jpa spec as

```
functions_returning_numerics::=
    SIZE(collection_valued_path_expression)

collection_valued_path_expression ::=
    general_identification_variable.{single_valued_object_field.}*collection_valued_field
```

Which means you have to pass the actual property to the `SIZE` function instead of only the variable name. Can you try the following query instead:

```
SELECT NEW de.poyry.pqgenerator.view.PqListItem(
 pq.id,
 pq.name,
 pq.submissionDate,
 pe.firstName,
 pe.lastName,
 SIZE(pq.partnerships))
FROM Prequalification pq
 JOIN pq.user us
 JOIN us.person pe
GROUP BY pq.id, pq.name, pq.submissionDate, pe.firstName, pe.lastName
```

Note that I also removed the joins for `pa.company` and `pq.partnerships` since they weren't used and added the non-aggregate fields to the `GROUP BY` expression as required by the JPA and SQL standard.

> The requirements for the `SELECT` clause when `GROUP BY` is used follow those of SQL: namely, any
>   item that appears in the `SELECT` clause (other than as an aggregate function or as an argument to an
>   aggregate function) must also appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: I only don't see why I need the `, pq.name, pq.submissionDate, pe.firstName, pe.lastName` fields in the `GROUP BY` as only pq.id yields the same list of PQ items.

Answer (score 2):

If you add a constructor that takes an int instead of Integer does it work?
That seems to be the issue.

I think this is fixed in the EclipseLink 2.4 stream, Integer or int should now work.